# How to create a jar file in netbeans with multiple frames

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, jar

I am trying to create the jar file by clean and build method and it created a file in dist folder but it's not working when I tried to run.
As one more thing I didn't see anyone created jar file with multiple frames as in my project and I am getting one error too during clean and build.

[image]

Comment: You need to say more than just “it’s not working.”  What are you expecting to see, and what did you see instead?  Also, do not post pictures of text.  Paste it into your question as actual characters.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: So what happens when you run `java -jar "E:\SafeBox\dist\SafeBox.jar"` from a command line as suggested?  Does your application require other libraries (jar files)? If yes, did you enable the "Copy Dependent Libraries" option in the "Packaging" section of the project properties?

Answer (score -1):

You must write the command to run the application: **java -jar  safeBox.jar**

What happens when you try to execute the command?

Comment: Nothing happened as i mentioned it only showing the jar file but not running